# Wordpress tag grouping

Tags: wordpress

I am currently working on a WordPress powered project and using tags for filtering content.
The problem I am having is that I want to establish some sort of hierarchical view of posts based on tags. Is there a way to have a hierarchical structure of tags or maybe groups of tags?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tags are not hierarchical - there's no way to indicate a parent/child relationship. The in-built category taxonomy is hierarchical however.  Alternatively you could create your own 'Tag' taxonomy and make it hierarchical. In fact, thinking about it, you may possibly be able to change the existing post tag taxonomy to make it hierarchical like the categories.

You can also view tags as a tag cloud which may help you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud

**Update:** some answers on the following question are using custom meta boxes to enable adding of tags (auto-complete etc), but when setting up the tags they can have parent/child relationships, it depends on what you're trying to achieve I guess: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26048/use-tag-interface-for-hierarchical-taxonomy